# 255 character truncation when copy/pasting a Data View from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2010, copy-paste

I've seen some stuff online about exporting data, but what I'm doing is a Copy/Paste.  I'm looking at a Datasheet View of an Access form, and I'm trying to copy it to Excel.  The form has 2 Memo fields.

If I copy the Memo fields one at a time, I get all the contents of the field.  If I try to copy the whole Datasheet View and paste it into Excel, the Memo fields get truncated.

Is there a way around this, other than exporting the data?

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to export.

Note that the error is in Excel, not in Access - if you paste to a text editor, or view the copied data in [Clipboard Viewer](http://freeclipboardviewer.com/), you see that the clipboard data is complete.

But when you paste multiple cells to Excel, it truncates each cell at 255 characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you Paste Special into Excel your text from Access will not be truncated.  But check to make sure funny things didn't happen in other columns of your Excel worksheet.  And you will end up with with a top line header you'll probably want to delete.  Small price to pay for getting all the text over.